# Exported Blender Normal Maps Look Wrong in Unreal Engine

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map, unreal-engine

This mentions Unreal Engine but the problem is in Blender.

I'm creating a small hallway and exported it as fbx to use it in Unreal Engine 4.
I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghRkH-KkjhE) tutorial for baking and exporting.

When I placed it in Unreal Engine I noticed something weird with the lighting:
[image: Unreal view]

In the image above, if you look closely, the left side of the point light (identified with the lamp icon) appears basically dark on the wall while at the right side has actual light. You can tell the lighting is incorrect by the light reflection on the floor.

I know this is a problem with the normal map in blender because if I delete the normal map in Unreal the issue dissapears and, sadly, I'm left with a relatively cheap version on the wall material.

[image: Blender view]
Blender view of the hallway with a point light

I've searched everywhere for this and couldn't find anyone with this issue.
Any help is appreciated. I've been hitting my head for days.

I have a backup collection with the original mesh and unbaked textures and another with the mesh with the baked textures, I Also inverted the green channel in the baked normal map.

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Of course. I flipped the green channel in the normal map of the baked texture. Also I have a backup collection with the unbaked textures.

Comment: Your normal map is referenced as sRGB in Blender, when it should almost certainly be non-color.  The images aren't packed into the file, and it's not clear whether this is an issue that will affect Unreal, but if you bake normals to sRGB, and unreal reads normals as non-color, which it almost certainly does, you'd see a shift like you're describing.  This isn't the only potential cause of issues, but it's not clear what normal map you're trying to use in Unreal, and it's not clear how you created it (high to low bake?)

Comment: I don't know what hight to low bake is so I figure I didn't use it. I'm not really an expert in blender. I'll try the non-color and post a screenshot of the bake settings.

Comment: @Nathan Thank you soooo much. You're literally my saviour. I almost started getting depressed because of this. I didn't set the "Non-Color" Setting. I don't want to get over emotional but really, you just made my day! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a few days of struggling I was able to solve this problem.
All of the credit goes to [Nathan](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24636/nathan)!

The issue was when I was creating the image to bake the Normal Map to, the Color Space setting was automatically set to sRGB. All I had to do is change it to Non-Color and voila! It started giving me a correct circle relfection on the wall.

But wait! This doesn't mean everything was fixed. I still had to invert the green channel so that the normals were dark and bright in the correct sides.

That was it. I hope this post helps people with with issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Blender uses OpenGL normals, while Unreal - DirectX. To convert one format to another, invert Green channel:

[image]

[image]

Here is the list of applications that you can check if you have to convert normal maps:

| Application | Normals |
| --- | --- |
| Blender | OpenGL |
| 3DS Max | DirectX |
| AMD | OpenGL |
| Arnold | OpenGL |
| Cinema 4D | OpenGL |
| Corona Renderer | DirectX |
| CryEngine | DirectX |
| Godot Engine | DirectX |
| Houdini | OpenGL |
| IClone | OpenGL |
| KeyShot | DirectX |
| KeyShot 9+ | OpenGL |
| Marmoset Toolbag | OpenGL |
| Maya | OpenGL |
| Modo | OpenGL |
| Nvidia | DirectX |
| Octane Render | OpenGL |
| Redshift | OpenGL |
| Shade3D | OpenGL |
| Source | DirectX |
| Substance Designer | DirectX |
| Substance Painter | DirectX |
| Unity | OpenGL |
| UnrealEngine | DirectX |
| VRay | OpenGL |
| Zbrush | OpenGL |

BTW for me, texture looks right in Unreal and wrong in Blender. So maybe the texture is DirectX actualy

Comment: Thank you, I will try it in a few minutes. Does blender has this feature of I must do it in another program?

Comment: You can do it in 2D editor

Comment: BTW for me, texture looks right in Unreal and wrong in Blender. So maybe the texture is DirectX actualy

Comment: Well, I tried to flip the green channel but sadly it didn't change anything. I re-imported it to Unreal with the modified normal map and the result was the same.

What do you mean by looking right in Unreal and wrong in Blender? I don't understand.

Comment: Try clicking sRGB in texture settings then

Comment: It was already selected. I'll try to bake the textures again and see if that fixes it. I'll give an update later

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know what is the problem. I'll just find another way arround this.